# Solve little linear system in Fortran

Tags: fortran, numerical-methods, intel-mkl

I have 3x3 and 4x4 matrices A and I need to find a matrix X solution of

```
A*X=B
```

where B is a matrix, but determinant of A is around 0.0!. The size of A is 3x3 (or 4x4), and the size of B is 3xr (or 4xr). Since determinant of A is near to 0.0, I don't want (or can't) use the exact matrix inverse of A to find X, or Cramer algorithm (because divide by determinant of the matrix).

Note that

```
A*x(:,s) = B(:,s)
```

where B(:,s) is the column number s of the matrix B. So, my problem is solve a linear system with several right side terms.

I'm running my code in fortran using MKL library (for solve a big sparse matrix), so I can use something of that library.

What is a good idea to solve this? Maybe LU decomposition?

Comment: If you are asking about math and not about code, consider http://scicomp.stackexchange.com instead. Questions here should contain some code or a direct programming problem.

Comment: I don't really see a reason for the fortran tag now, you are just limiting your audience to a small number, not many people click on Fortran questions and you have no Fortran in the question.. But I recommend you to delete it here and go to scicomp.stackexchange.

Comment: First check if the near zero is really significant (if the array elements have small values, the determinant will be tiny). If it is, don't try to solve the near singular system before you have understood why it is so (error in evaluation of the coefficients ?). Otherwise, the best algorithm in the world won't help you.